# count function in sql oracle without using group by

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

how using count function in sql oracle without using group by?

```
select count(*) as "Total orders",
       nvl(
         (select count (*)
          from   education
          where status='APPROVED'),
         0
       ) as "Number of approved requests"
from   education
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
select COUNT(*) as "Total orders",
       COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'APPROVED' THEN 1 END)
         as "Number of approved requests"
from   education_expense
```